# output 2d boolean masked value by tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, boolean, mask

I have a [n,m] input and [n,m] boolean mask. How could I output a [n,x] filtered matrix, instead of [x] array?

For example, input

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

and a boolean mask

```
bm = [[1,0,1],[1,0,0]]
```

I tried to use tf.boolean_mask() and I got [1,3,4].
How could I get a 2D result like

```
result =  [[1,3],[4]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operation could not exist in TF because TF operates on the tensors and returns tensors. The result you received has different number of elements and not a tensor.

Comment: Yep, best you can do is the 1d tensor unless you want to use sentinel values.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in TF. However, you can consider using [Masked Array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) in numpy. You can do something like

```
>>> import numpy as np, numpy.ma as ma
>>> x = ma.array([1., -1., 3., 4., 5., 6.], mask=[0,0,0,0,1,0])
>>> y = ma.array([1., 2., 0., 4., 5., 6.], mask=[0,0,0,0,0,1])
>>> print np.sqrt(x/y)
[1.0 -- -- 1.0 -- --]
```